# Why didn't this new meta post show up in the moderator diamond menu?

Tags: support, moderator-tools, notifications

Moderators see notifications for new meta questions in the diamond menu.  Today a [new meta question](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2126/1993) appeared on one of my sites but the notification did not:

[image: screenshot]

The only difference I can see is that the new question was asked by Community, presumably by an automated process.  Do such posts somehow bypass moderator notifications?  Or is there a broader issue with meta notifications that I just haven't noticed yet?

The question is more than an hour old and I usually see these notifications nearly immediately.

Comment: That post is created automatically through a separate process which doesn't trigger a QuestionCreated event, and thus never creates any inbox item. We *could* probably trigger that event if moderators think it'd be useful for that to show up.

Comment: @animuson for this *specific* case I think the other notifications for the event itself are sufficient, but are there other members of the class -- other auto-posts that bypass notification?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure. This post is literally created manually by creating its own object and adding all the relevant information then submitting straight to the database rather than going through the normal post creation code. I'd assume all the election posts do similar things, but there's no way of knowing what other things might also do that since it's not connected to anything.

Comment: I do recall this happening for election posts and I don't recall this happening for any other post.